# Redirect to previous page not working

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have used windows.history.back() to return user to previous page. now this command is not working but when i put debugger and do debug then page is getting redirect to previous page. but without debugging in firebug it is not working . 
i have also **tried windows.go(-1)**. and even i tried all this option after clearing cache. still not working
can anyone tell me what is problem? or give me alternative way to get browser back button functionality using java script/J Query or asp.net c#.

Comment: Have you tried `windows.history.go(-1)` ??

Comment: i have also tried this. It is not working for me

Comment: Please put your code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just try to use html button instead of asp.net button or put return false at the end of javascript
may be server side click is being called

Answer (score 2):

You can use `C#` Coding also for it.

On Button click

```
if (Request.UrlReferrer != null)
{
Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Which control are you using to write code to previous page.

```
If you're using Asp:Button 
write the javascript code on onclientclick event 
window.history.go(-1)

If you're using Html button 
write the javascript code on onclick event 
window.history.go(-1)

If you're using anchor tag <a> 
write the javascript code to href attribute
<a href="javascript:window.history.go(-1);">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 onclick="window.history.go(-1)"
```

Comment: it is not working. i am getting redirect to same page.

Comment: have you set `href=#` ?